# Problem reading a file with FileSystem Capacitor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I want to download and read files, to achieve that I am using the Capacitor FileSystem plugin. At the time of downloading the files they are saved in the indexedDB, but when trying to read the file it says that it cannot find it even though the file does exist and I give it the correct path, any idea what could be the reason?

This is the code:

```
        Filesystem.writeFile({
          path:name,
          data:base64,
          directory:FilesystemDirectory.Data,
          encoding: FilesystemEncoding.UTF8,
          recursive:true
        }).then((resp:FileWriteResult)=>{
          Filesystem.readFile({
            path:resp.uri
          }).then(resp=>{
            console.log(resp);
          }).catch(err=>console.log(err));
        }).catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

This is the error:

Error: File does not exist.

Comment: Are you sure the DB is storing the image?

Comment: @Kinglish Yes, the download works fine, at least in the browser